# How can I complete this code of question: find the kid with greatest number of candies

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int kids;
    cout << "Enter the number of kids: " << endl;
    cin >> kids;

    int candies;
    cout << "Enter the number of candies: " << endl;
    cin >> candies;

    int candies_arr[kids];
    for (int i = 0; i <= kids - 1; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the candies you want to give to kid " << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> candies_arr[i];
    }
    int maxCandy = INT_MIN;
    int minCandy = INT_MAX;

    for (int i = 0; i <= kids - 1; i++)
    {
        if (candies_arr[i] > maxCandy)
        {
            maxCandy = candies_arr[i];
        }
        if (candies_arr[i] < minCandy)
        {
            minCandy = candies_arr[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "The maximum candies were: " << maxCandy << endl;
    cout << "The minimum candies were: " << minCandy << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

How can I do changes in the arrays and do something so that I can find exactly the kid who has highest number of candies?

Comment: `int candies_arr[kids];` should be `std::vector<int> candies_arr(kids);`

Comment: `i <= kids - 1` is just a cumbersome way of writing `i < kids`

Comment: You can use [std::minmax_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) to save hassle: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/q5Efr3Mx7)

Answer (score 1):

You can just add another variable to store the index of the greatest and smallest indexes.

```
int maxCandy = INT_MIN;
int maxIndex = 0;
int minCandy = INT_MAX;
int minIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= kids - 1 /*i < kids*/; i++)
{
    if (candies_arr[i] > maxCandy)
    {
        maxCandy = candies_arr[i];
        maxIndex = i;
    }
    if (candies_arr[i] < minCandy)
    {
        minCandy = candies_arr[i];
        minIndex = i;
    }
}
```

When printing number of kid with most candies.

```
cout << "Most candies has the kid " << i + 1 << endl;
```